# Assigning values to unmapped property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

Suppose, I have a Customer class with some properties like

- name,
- id,
- object of CompetentAuthority class etc.

name,id etc is mapped in .hbm file but i have taken icollection of CompetentAuthority object and I didnt do any entery in .hbm file for CompetentAuthority(one-to-many).

In CompetentAuthority class i have taken Customer object and in .hbm file of CompetentAuthority i did many-to-one relationship.

Nnow,i want list of customers with it's CompetentAuthority list but as its just an object and no mapping is done,criteria API doesn't allow me to do innerjoin;it gives me error like "cannot resolve property"

Is there any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting to use the Criteria API to apply an INNER JOIN, then no you cannot do that. The CompetentAuthority object needs to be mapped with NHibernate and the Customer object's mapping file will need to be modified to establish the relationship between the two entities.

If for some reason you are not able to map the CompetentAuthority, you could take advantage of mixing the ISession.CreateSQLQuery() method and the Transformers.AliasToBean() method which will allow you to hydrate an unmapped entity.

For more information on this technique, please refer to the Official NHibernate documentation section titled "Returning non-managed entities" or search around for using the AliasToBean() method: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#d0e11066

Comment: hey Randy, thank you for your reply,and this solution work for me :) but CreateSQLQuery() is for SQL Database right? it ll not work if DB is in Oracal or mysql right?if yes then can i do it any other way.

Comment: CreateSQLQuery() will work for all databases supported by NHibernate.